# 2 background color with an image

Tags: css

I am trying to do two background color (black and grey) with an image. 
The color black is OK and the image also. However the color grey is missing...

[image]

I have a problem in my blocks ?

Thank you

```css
.image-item-2-03{
 float: left;
 height: 390px;
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 40%;
}

.background-black{
 background-color: #222222;
 position: absolute;
 width: 65%;
}

.background-grey{
 background-color:grey;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-black">
<img class="image-item-2-03" src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/13/alfk.jpg" alt="">
<div class="background-grey">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to stack the backgrounds on top of each other? Like the grey background is supposed to be on top of the black one, and a little smaller?

Comment: Try adding height to your grey div...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not clear, but if you want the gray background on the left of the image, and the black on the right, then you need to reaarange the blocks a little. I've used inline-blocks instead of absolutely positioned divs as they are much easier to control:

```css
.image-item-2-03{
  display: inline-block; 
 height: 390px;
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 60%;
  margin: none;
}

.background-black{
 background-color: #222222;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20%;
  height: 390px;
  margin: none;
}

.background-grey{
 background-color:grey;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20%;
  height: 390px;
  margin: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-black"></div><img class="image-item-2-03" src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/13/alfk.jpg" alt=""><div class="background-grey"></div>
```

Comment: No problem, @user11124425 :)

Answer (score 1):

It's there, but its `height` is zero. Set it to some number.

```css
.image-item-2-03{
 float: left;
 height: 390px;
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 40%;
}

.background-black{
 background-color: #222222;
 position: absolute;
 width: 65%;
}

.background-grey{
 background-color:grey;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-black">
<img class="image-item-2-03" src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/13/alfk.jpg" alt="">
<div class="background-grey">
hello!
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I do not fully understand your question, I think from what you've said that you want to place the grey background on top the black one. Making the image on the very top of the stack.

Here is the code for that:

CSS

```
.image-item-2-03 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 390px;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 40%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.background-black {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #222222;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -200;
}

.background-grey {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: grey;
   padding: 10% 10% 10% 45%;
   height: 70px;
   z-index: -100;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="background-black">

<img class="image-item-2-03" src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/13/alfk.jpg" alt="">

<div class="background-grey">
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1wvk53mc/98/ for the output

Comment: thank you Compiler my problem is solve now. thank you

Comment: Make sure to check mark my answer to make sure others see it as the correct one if it solved your problem.